# Can an uncountable union of distinct finite sets be countable or even finite?

Tags: set-theory

Does there exist an uncountable set of distinct finite sets such that their union is countable, or even finite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There does not. Suppose that $\mathscr{F}$ is a family of finite sets, and let $X=\bigcup\mathscr{F}$. If $X$ were countable, it would have only countably many finite subsets, so $X$ must be uncountable.

More generally, if $X$ is a set of cardinality $\kappa$ for some infinite cardinal $\kappa$, then $X$ has only $\kappa$ distinct finite subsets.

Answer (score 1):

No. Suppose that we have a collection of sets $\{X_i\}_{i \in I}$ for some $I$ an uncountable index set. Recall how we'll define their union:

$$\bigcup_{i \in I} X_i = \{ x \mid \exists i \in I \text{ such that } x \in X_i \}$$

This allows you to very naturally produce an injection $I \to \bigcup X_i$: you can send each $i \in I$ to some $x \in \bigcup X_i$, based on the condition that $x$ is in that very $X_i$. In other words, you're sending each element of the index set, to some element in the union, where that element comes from one of the sets indexed by that element of the index set.

By this, then, $|I| \le | \bigcup X_i |$. So the size of the union must be uncountable if $I$ is.